# The bottom of my black cheap pan has worn off and I can now see the metal below where food would go. Is that pan safe to use anymore?

Tags: food-safety, pan

As part of my "kitchen inventory package" my short stay agency gave me for my cooking, there's a pan. After a couple of mistakes (cough using it to heat sauce without adding oil (as instructed!) then not cleaning the pan up immediately) and much cleaning, I can now see I ended up scratching the 'black' off my pan.

Is the pan still safe to use, or do I need to buy a new one? What could go possibly wrong if I did use it and why?

Comment: I'm surprised I couldn't find a dupe of this question

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: @soegaard Not right now I'm afraid.

Comment: Is(Was) it non stick?

Comment: @badp You should clarify the type of the pan first, whether it is non-stick, cast iron, etc. Indicating only the colour isn't sufficient to decide the type.

Comment: @MissesBrown There's no label on it and if there was one it's worn off. I didn't buy the pan. I honestly have no idea :/

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to assume that this is a non-stick coated aluminum (*maybe* s/s) pan and specifically Teflon or one of the common knock-offs; those are the only types of pans I've seen that are *white* under the black coating. If you had well-seasoned cast iron, it would be grayish colour (well, *iron*).

It's not *unsafe* in the same sense as eating raw meat is unsafe, but there are some things you should know:

1. The base metal (under the coating), if it is in fact aluminum, now has a reactive surface. That means you won't be able to cook anything with vinegar, wine, tomatoes, or anything acidic, without further damaging the pan and leaching metal into your food.
2. Once a non-stick coating gets scratched, if there's any left, it also starts to *peel*, and once it starts peeling then it's very easy for it to get into your food. [According to DuPont, the chemical PTFE is inert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene#Safety) as long as it is not heated to extreme temperatures, so you shouldn't get seriously ill if you happen to eat a few flakes of it by accident. Make your own decision.
3. Your non-stick pan almost certainly isn't going to be *non-stick* anymore, which means that even though it probably won't harm you, it *will* be a truly awful cooking surface.

On the basis of #3 alone, I'd suggest that you replace it with a new one, especially since it was cheap to begin with.

Comment: Now I have to check if it's actually white or not. Well, it's not; it's... metal grey. I'm sorry

Comment: @badp: How heavy is the pan, and does a magnet stick to it? Cast iron is pretty easy to spot; it has a porous surface and is heavier than any other kind of cookware. If it's anything other than cast iron then everything stated above still generally applies.

Comment: The pan is fairly heavy, heavier that what I've used otherwise. I don't have a magnet handy and I'd rather not try with my hard drive.

Comment: @badp: "Fairly heavy" isn't a very precise measure. Trust me, you'll *know* if it's cast iron because it will be *really, really heavy*, and again, have a porous, not smooth, surface. If it's just "kinda sorta" heavy and the exterior is steel or some other smooth metal then you don't have cast iron.

Comment: A 12" cast iron pan weighs [~8lbs](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00006JSUB)/3.6kg. Varies a little by manufacturer of course, but that should give an idea.

Comment: Point 1 needs clarifying. Aluminium is not just reactive with acids but it is one of the few metals that reacts with alkalis also. When exposed to air, it forms an oxide readily which reacts more readily with alkalis than acids. There are bare aluminium pans and cookware available. Most importantly, this point ends with "leaching metal into your food" and begs the question "and?". Cast iron pans leach iron into food too. It is just a fact. Is there an insinuation that this is unsafe?